# importing JQuery Responsive Navbar doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a nav bar responsive but it doesn't work. I was using the JQuery from Google but since I am currently in China it doesn't work. So I copied the content of the JQuery file into a file named jquery-3.3.1.min.js that I stored in the same directory of my Header file.

It still doesn't open from my phone. I attach the code here below:

```
<head>
 <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <title>International Corporate Finance</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<!-- NAVBAR --> 
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Pippo</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="http://ec2-13-133-18-154.aws.com/Actions.php">Actions</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ec2-13-133-18-154.aws.com/Actions.php/CompaniesInput.php">New Companies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ec2-13-133-18-154.aws.com/Actions.php/AllCompanies.php">View Companies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ec2-13-133-18-154.aws.com/Actions.php/Search.php">Search Companies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ec2-13-133-18-154.aws.com/">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: @kag, Actually yes: "filed to load resource: the server responded with a status 404 jquery-3.3.1.min.js". But the file is there, I dont know if I am doing it right but I pasted into a text file this: [link]https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: so it is clear. You just need to update the correct path of your file.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have have the wrong path. Make sure your jquery.min.js file is the correct path. if you can post a picture of your folder structure would be nice for us to help you if you keep having the problem. Also, another solution would be to use the cdn instead. Example: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi, I cannot use the Google repository for the JQuery because I am in China and I cannot access it. My path is ../www/html/header.php and the file is in the directory html as per the instructions provided here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

I walked around the issue using Microsoft CDN

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```